# trying to plot two Pivot table in one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
gh1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
temp1.plot(kind='bar')
gh1.set_xlabel('credit_history')
gh1.set_ylabel('count of credit history')
gh1.set_title('Applicants by credit history')
gh2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
temp2.plot(kind='bar')
gh2.set_xlabel('credit_history')
gh2.set_ylabel('Probability of loan by credit history')
gh2.set_title('Probability of getting loan by credit history')
plt.show()
```

output coming

[print of second subgraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACj9E.png)

[print of first subgraph with no values in second subgraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG3CP.png)

question is why it's printing second subgraph separatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created the subplots, however you are not using them when you are plotting the graph. You need pass the subplots as arguments into the plotting function by doing `ax=gh1`.

You code should look like:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

gh1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
temp1.plot(kind='bar', ax=gh1)  # pass in subplot as an argument
gh1.set_xlabel('credit_history')
gh1.set_ylabel('count of credit history')
gh1.set_title('Applicants by credit history')

gh2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
temp2.plot(kind='bar', ax=gh2)  # pass in subplot as an argument
gh2.set_xlabel('credit_history')
gh2.set_ylabel('Probability of loan by credit history')
gh2.set_title('Probability of getting loan by credit history')

plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks man...it's working. Actually i was guessing something i suppose to pass but not having the idea which parameter i suppose to use...pls tell me that how can i check such things in pycharm IDE

Comment: @AbhishekSingh No problem. If one of the answers solved your problem you could mark as accepted. The best bet would be to look at the documentation to find out what parameters are valid https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Answer (score 0):

I find that plt.subplots works best for this type of stuff. I'll give you a simple example and you can generalize it to your code.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8,6))
temp1.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1)
temp2.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2)
fig.show()
```

This accomplishes the same as what you are wanting but with a more succinct notation and tends to work better, especially for a large number of subplots. For example we could do:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8,6))
temp1.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[0])
temp2.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax[1])
fig.show()
```

Instead wich is a bit messier here for just 2 plots but generalizes nicely to a collection of N subplots.

Comment: can you pls tell me how to plot pivot table in this way

Comment: I edited it to show it specifically for the example you are looking for. Should work now.